# How do I clean cached paths to modules?

Tags: 7, caching, files

I foolishly did this, when updating a module:

```
# cd /var/www/drupal7/modules
# mv MODULE MODULE.old
# wget <MODULE_URL> -O - | tar xfvz -
```

After refreshing the module list, I still get the old module's version because, surprise, it found the MODULE.old subdirectory first. Or last. Or whatever.

I can of course do

```
# rm -r MODULE.old
# ln -s MODULE MODULE.old
```

but that's a temporary measure at best.

How do I remove these MODULE.old directories? `drush cc` also tries to access them and won't run if they're not there!

Comment: It's just my guess, but try to 1) disable said module 2) remove .old directory 3) clear all caches 4) enable module. If this or similar procedure will work, feel free to post it as self-answer, or to comment @ me and tell me to do it ;)

Comment: Wouldn't disabling these modules drop the database tables they created?

Comment: False, **uninstalling** them clears database tables, **disabling** does not.

Comment: Ah, OK, will try then.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to disable the module, remove the '.old' folder and then re-enable the module. Unless disabling the module is destructive, this is the course of action I would recommend.

Otherwise you need to call [registry_rebuild](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/registry_rebuild/7), though as you've realised you can't do this from a module because your site won't bootstrap. There is drush command made just for this case which you can find at https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

If none of this works, you will need to manually edit the database ; you will need to manually edit the 'system' table and clear the system cache. Not recomended.

Whichever option you go for, make a backup of your database first!

Comment: +1 for `drush rr` very useful for these situations

Comment: … except when it doesn't work: drush rr
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function module_load_include() in /srv/www/drupal7/modules/entity/entity.module on line 8`

Answer (score 0):

Since `drush rr` does not work in my setup for whatever reason, I ended up hacking a temporary path cleanup function to bootstrap.inc.

```
--- /usr/share/drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc       2014-02-13 11:26:07.710709587 +0000
+++ /tmp/boots      2014-02-13 11:26:04.722628976 +0000
@@ -3100,6 +3100,21 @@
  *   TRUE if the resource was found, FALSE if not.
  *   NULL if either of the REGISTRY_* constants is passed in as $type.
  */
+
+function _fixpath($fn) {
+  $last = "";
+  $pieces = explode("/", $fn);
+  $p = array();
+  foreach ($pieces as $pp) {
+    if (fnmatch("*.old",$pp)) { $pp = substr($pp,0,-4); }
+    if ($pp == "OLD") { continue; }
+    if ($last == $pp) { continue; }
+    $last = $pp;
+    $p[] = $pp;
+  }
+  return implode("/",$p);
+}
+
 function _registry_check_code($type, $name = NULL) {
   static $lookup_cache, $cache_update_needed;

@@ -3136,7 +3152,7 @@
   $cache_key = $type[0] . $name;
   if (isset($lookup_cache[$cache_key])) {
     if ($lookup_cache[$cache_key]) {
-      require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $lookup_cache[$cache_key];
+      require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . _fixpath($lookup_cache[$cache_key]);
     }
     return (bool) $lookup_cache[$cache_key];
   }
@@ -3158,7 +3174,7 @@
   $lookup_cache[$cache_key] = $file;

   if ($file) {
-    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;
+    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . _fixpath($file);
     return TRUE;
   }
   else {
```

After running `drush cc` I could remove that hack.